# Build a dist like object to feed into hclust

Tags: r

I want to build a distance matrix but I already have the distances. How can I do it?

Distances are simply t-values between factors in a linear regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `as.dist(m)`, where `m` is your distance matrix.

Comment: Yep, I discovered it later on. Thanks!